# SSIS package failing as part of SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS package from a SQL Server agent job, the package fails when setting a string value (guid).

The error is -

***Executed as user: USER_X. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.4276.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  17:47:18  DTExec: Could not set In_Config_SourceHash value to 575afdef-5cd0-4b72-beaa-cf5884af8e56.  Started:  17:47:18  Finished: 17:47:39  Elapsed:  20.685 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.***

The command line details are -

***/FILE "\tc2aifs001\scv\client\Client_ImportSourceData_Main.dtsx"  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /SET "In_Config_SourceHash";"575afdef-5cd0-4b72-beaa-cf5884af8e56" /SET "In_Config_SourceShortName";ClientName /SET "In_Config_ConfigHash";"ec137cf6-1cf9-4478-9e6d-fc3ca6623fbe" /SET "In_Config_ConfigName";ClientNameDevelopment /SET "In_Config_PackageUNCDirectory";"\tc2aifs001\SCV\packages\client\" /SET "In_Config_PackageNamePrefix";"Client_ImportSourceData_" /REPORTING E***

The job is running a SSIS package from the file system and it is running as the SQL Server agent service account.

In_Config_Source hash is a varchar variable and works fine when set to the guid value I am trying to set when running through visual studio.

Does anyone know why this is failing? Or any ideas on what to look for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the exact content of the jobstep from your agent job. Go into the "Command line" tab and post it here

Comment: My guess is that you are passing the value in as `575afdef-5cd0-4b72-beaa-cf5884af8e56` and it needs to be `{575afdef-5cd0-4b72-beaa-cf5884af8e56}` or something dumb like this

Comment: Apologies, I have been on holiday. This has been amended to include the command line.